# Jekyll default installation doesn't have _layouts directory

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

So I followed the guide on the Jekyll website by installing and running Jekyll (sure I don't have to post this here). And the site is up and running perfectly but for some reason I don't see the `_layouts` directory that's supposed to be there. In the pages I can see that it references some layouts i.e:

**index.html**

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="home">
```

**about.md**

```
---
layout: page
title: About
permalink: /about/
---

This is the base Jekyll theme.
```

But when you look at the directory stucture of the project:

[image]

No layouts folder.. what's up with that? Everything works though. And it looks perfectly fine when run on localhost.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You must be running the recent Jekyll version 3.2, which introduces Gem based themes (from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/):

> Jekyll themes package layouts, includes, and stylesheets in a way that can be overridden by your site’s content.

The theme is set in _config.yml:

```
theme: minima
```

Initial files that were previously in `_layouts`, `_includes`, and `_sass` are now packaged with the theme.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is there a way to add a  new Jekyll 3.2 website withouth the minima theme?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `theme: minima` line from your `_config.yml`. You could copy the theme files to your site as well if you wanted to keep the starting point: https://github.com/jekyll/minima

Comment: Is there any automatic way to do this? i.e. without downloading from github?

Comment: You could copy the files from where bundle installs them instead. I've been using an older version of Jekyll to generate new sites: `jekyll _3.0.3_ new .` (assuming macOS with Jekyll 3.0.3 installed).

Comment: I don't see the themes folder for `minima`.

Comment: @zachdyer I'm not sure what you mean. If you're still having issues it's probably better to ask in a new question.

Comment: I guess I didn't have the minima theme installed. However I solved the problems I was having by deleting the gem files and adding the `_layouts` folder and other Jekyll folders to the root directory. Then it started working just fine.

Comment: So if I want to build off of the minima theme, say adding a header.html include, how would I go about doing this? Would I have to make a new theme entirely?

Comment: To clarify then, if one wants to make additions or modifications to their layouts, they must either manually create folders and copy files from somewhere under _site, or they must modify a gem and maintain a custom gem?  If so, both options seem quite user-unfriendly.  A step or two more in that direction and we might as well just hand-code a site like we used to.

Answer (score 15):

Basically Jekyll wants you to use themes, so you can't see `_layouts`, `_includes`, `_sass`, `_assets` anymore.

To use previous behaviour simply copy from the gemfile:

```
open $(bundle show minima)
```

Copy the 4 folders into your jekyll directory

Comment: Interesting. Should I delete files in minima?

Comment: You don't have to delete files in minima. The files in your project directory are preferentially used

Comment: or you can use `open $(bundle show minima)` to access the minima files directly (works from mac terminals).

Comment: Getting this message in terminal: `bash: open: command not found`

Comment: @YashuMittal On Ubuntu/Linux, try `xdg-open $(bundle show minima)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the older style of Jekyll website directory which includes all the 4 folders then you can use this command : 
`jekyll new my-new-website-name --blank`
I have done the same while creating a personal site.

Comment: This just seems to initiate the some directories. The default theme which we can edit is not present here.