# add Google analytics to jekyll blog

Tags: github, google-analytics, jekyll

As far as I understand, `jekyll new` from 3.2.1 doesn't create `_layout`, `_include` and everything like that, so that it only states `theme: minima` and all includes and layouts are encapsulated in the theme as stated in another answer [Jekyll default installation doesn't have _layouts directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891463/jekyll-default-installation-doesnt-have-layouts-directory).

I'd like to add Google analytics to my new site, how do I do that now? In the past I'd just add it to `_includes/footer.html` or whatever.

Alternatively, how do I just create blog all these directories and files like before (without copying it from somewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/#overriding-theme-defaults), you just need to manually create your own versions of the theme's templates under `_layouts` and `_includes`. If you look in the [minima theme repository](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) you can see the templates that you can override.