# Jekyll site did generate underscore folders?

Tags: jekyll

After installing **Jekyll** the first site I generated (as per tutorial) did not generate underscore folders (`_includes`, `_Layouts`, `_sass`). Only generated `_posts`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jekyll default installation doesn't have \_layouts directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891463/jekyll-default-installation-doesnt-have-layouts-directory)

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.2, those files and folders from the `jekyll new` command are stored within the Gem-based themes. I answered this here: [Jekyll default installation doesn't have _layouts directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891463/jekyll-default-installation-doesnt-have-layouts-directory/38891696#38891696)

---

> You must be running the recent Jekyll version 3.2, which introduces Gem based themes (from https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/):
>
> Jekyll themes package layouts, includes, and stylesheets in a way that can be overridden by your site’s content. The theme is set in `_config.yml`:
>
> ```
> theme: minima
> ```
>
> Initial files that were previously in `_layouts`, `_includes`, and `_sass` are now packaged with the theme.

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Thanks appreciate that clarification (yes I'm running 3.2.1)